# Upsert a document pushing an object into an array with Mongodb and Javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm stuck with this problem and I hope to find someone who can help me.

I need to search for a document in a collection, if it exists I need to pull an object inside an array, otherwise I want to insert the document.

Somehow, I keep on receiving this error: **Updating the path 'shifts.0' would create a conflict at 'shifts'**

```
const document = {
    name: 'John',
    surname: 'Doe',
    shifts: {
        '0': [{date:'2023-06-01', hours: 4}, {date:'2023-06-02', hours: 6}],
        '1': [{date:'2023-06-03', hours: 2}, {date:'2023-06-04', hours: 7}],
    },
};

const search = {name: 'John', surname: 'Doe'};};

const shift0 = {date: '2023-07-01',hours: '1'};
const shift1 = {date: '2023-07-02',hours: '1'};

const users = db.collection("users");
users.updateOne(
    search,
    {
        $setOnInsert: document,
        $push: {
            'shifts.0': shift0,
            'shifts.1': shift1,
        }
    },
    {
        upsert: true
    }
);
```